# What is a "new user" for the purposes of the time limitations on posting?

Tags: discussion

I'm referring to the 40 minute limitation after a "new user" has posed a question on another site, and the 24 hour limitation for a downvoted question.

I am on about 80 SE sites, 20 or so with over 1000 rep, about 20 with 200-999 rep, and 40 with less than 200 rep.

I recently ran into the [40 minute time limit](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/what-is-the-40-minute-rule-about) on a site with about 150 rep at the time. I presume that I was a "new user" then. I wonder if I would still be considered a new user today, with 255 rep, given that I've crossed one threshold (200 rep).

Basically, I'd like to get a sense of which of my sites (at what rep levels) the time limitations would apply. Or is "new user" defined by something else, such as days on the site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one post every 40 minutes network-wide affects users with less than 125 reputation. So if all your network profiles have 101 reputation, you'd be limited on all of those (at the time you posted that question on Open Data Meta, you had 121 reputation). Your profile here, having over 2,000 reputation, would not be limited but, as you've found out, posting here would limit you on another site where you don't have 125 reputation.

The "24 hour limitation for a downvoted question" is likely the automated quality block, which has nothing to do with your reputation and is purely based on the votes on your existing questions. It ranges anywhere from 1 day to 7 days depending on your history. If your very first question on the site gets downvoted, then it's very likely you'll get hit with a 1-day block.

Comment: How does "history" come into play? Even on my best site, (History by the way), I will occasionally have a downvoted question. But I have many more "good" ones.

Comment: As long as you don't have a history of bad questions, you're pretty safe from being blocked. However, the quality block only looks at the current site.

Comment: So do you mean "net" downvoted questions on a site? Do you mean that one won't be blocked if there are 5 (or 50) upvoted questions "ahead" of the downvoted one? And there might be a seven day block if you have, say, five downvoted questions with no offsetting good ones?

Comment: Exactly. An occasional downvoted question is no big deal if you have tons of upvotes ones already. The block is meant to stop people with downvoted questions making up a huge portion of their existing questions.

Comment: And what happens if you have 10,000 rep, all from answers, and your first question gets downvoted? So "rep" comes into play only if it is "question" rep (upvotes on many questions)?

Comment: @TomAu - Questions and Answers are considered to be separate for the purposes of determining the quality of a question or answer..